# « J'ai la conviction que » + futur simple ou conditionnel ?

Tags: mode-grammatical, conditionnel, futur-simple

Je doute entre les deux usages suivants:

> J'ai la conviction que mes compétences vous seront...

ou

> J'ai la conviction que mes compétences vous seraient...

C'est une phrase destinée à un recruteur.

Comment: Il faudrait que tu donnes un emploi en contexte pour justifier le choix entre « seront », futur simple et « seraient » conditionnel (le « conditionnel futur » n'existe pas). L'emploi du futur « seront » implique une quasi certitude de la part du locuteur, quasi certitude renforcée par l'emploi du mot « conviction ».  L'emploi du conditionnel « seraient » est en contradiction avec le sentiment de conviction, mais fait montre par ailleurs d'une certaine humilité. Donc au final tout dépend de la force de cette conviction et de l'impression que tu veux donner à l'employeur potentiel.

Comment: @Laure, merci pour votre feedback. Je suis d'accord avec vous et j'opte pour le futur simple tant qu'il ne contredit pas mon sentiment de conviction. +1 d'avoir invoqué l'humilité et sa relation avec le conditionnel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vous pouvez employer le futur simple comme le conditionnel ici. Comme l'a mentionné Laure dans son commentaire le contexte est déterminant:

- J'ai la conviction que cet exemple serait déterminant si l'usage du
  conditionnel révélait une condition.
- J'ai la conviction que cet exemple sera déterminant dans vos futurs
  choix.

Toutefois, si je peux me permettre ici de vous donner un conseil, comme il s'agit d'une lettre de recrutement :
Ne laissez pas planer le doute avec l'emploi du conditionnel.
L'emploi du futur est à préférer au conditionnel mais uniquement si vous vous forcez à choisir entre les deux.
En effet, un recruteur appréciera d'avantages des faits, et donc le présent :

- J'ai la conviction que mes compétences sont factuelles, présentes et surtout intéressantes pour votre Entreprise.

Comment: +1, employer "j'ai la conviction" suivi d'un conditionnel est un peu paradoxal